# Cannot delete a route in redhat linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have the following entry in a redhat linux machine to reject the private network route:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.0        -                255.0.0.0       !         -   -      -   -
```

Now I want to delete this entry but I cannot delete it using `route del` command.

```
sudo route del -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
```

Can anyone please help me to delete this route?

Comment: uff.. I found it finally using google. It worked :D

**route del -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 reject**

Comment: Sorry but if you were able to find the answer in 5 minutes using Google why ask here first? :-) BTW you can post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: route del -net 203.82.62.170 netmask 255.255.255.255 reject definately work...thanks manny